# Resharper 8 and Test Explorer not finding xUnit tests in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, xunit, xunit.net

I have the following test code. But cant see the tests in either Test Explorer or Resharper.
What am I missing?  I have made the class public, I have tried cleaning the project, i have tried both default architectures in the test settings. I am running Windows 7.  xUnit 1.9.2, Resharper 8.1 Full Edition

```
using Xunit;
namespace MonkeyFace.Specs.Registration
{
    public class ValidApplicationReceived
    {
        [Trait("A valid application is submitted","")]
        [Fact(DisplayName= "A user is added to the system")]
        public void User_is_Add_To_System()
        {
            Debug.Print("hi");
            Assert.Equal(1,1);
        }
```

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have the xunit ReSharper runner extension installed? You need to install it from ReSharper -> Extension Manager.

If it's installed, do you see anything in the editor? Any icons next to the class or method to indicate tests?

Comment: Yes I had to do this for Resharper.

Comment: The runner extension works, but what about Traits? I can't seem to find anywhere in the ReSharper test runner to actually see the traits. All tests are listed under class name. Then method name with a '+' that you have to expand to see the DisplayName. This is awkward. Is there any way to make the runner display only Trait > DisplayName?

Comment: Yep, change the grouping drop down to group by category. If a trait has a name of "category", then it will use just the value as the category here. If it doesn't, it creates a string in the form `name[value]` and uses that as "category"

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the xUnit.net runner for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013  by using the Tools -> Extensions and Updates menu in Visual Studio

Comment: xUnit.net VSIX is deprecated, use the NuGet-based test runner instead. [(follow)](https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-vs.html)